# MonoDevelop widgets stucked in Insensitive StateType

Tags: c#, button, mono, gtk#

Once i set the state of a Button/Entry to "Insensitive":

```
button.State = Gtk.StateType.Insensitive;
```

It never goes back to the normal state during run-time:

```
button.State = Gtk.StateType.Normal;
```

What am I doing wrong?

(I've tried button.Sensitive = true/false and it does work... But the behaviour of "State" is still weird even if i solved the problem...)

Comment: Did you debug and made sure that the debugger actually **hit** the line in which you activate the button? And, are you sure that the container of the button is not insensitive too?

Comment: I've tried to put a Console.WriteLine to see if it pass through that part and it does; I am also sure that the container is Sensitive. (The container is the window itself in a test.)

Comment: AIUI, Widget.State only relates to the visual appearance. Does the button not react?

Answer (score 1):

I thought of answering this question even though it's old since there is no posted solution yet.

You must use

```
button.Sensitive = true;
```

I hope that helps.